# How to have a column with each object and add another row if the first row is filled in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, bootstrap-4

I am writing Java Servlet using MySQL. I want to display data in such a way that in each rows there are five columns. This is the table i want.

[image: table that i want]

Currently, I have six data items and i put them in list so in each list there are 5 items.
[a,b,c,d,e] , [f]

[image: table]

This is the table i currently have. I am not sure how to show each item in the way i want.

```
        //getting sql data
        List<Object> dataItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
        while (rset.next()) {
            SQLData item = new SQLData(rset.getString("name"), rset.getString("prod_desc"),
                    rset.getDouble("price"));
            dataItems.add(item);
        }

        //chuck list
        int size = 5;
        List<Object>[] partition = partition(dataItems, size);

        out.println("<div class='container' style='border:1px solid #cecece;'>");

        out.println("<div class='row'>");
        for (Object item : partition) {
            out.println("<div class='col'>");
            out.println("<p>" + item + " test </p>");
            out.println("</div>");
        }
        out.println("</div>");

        out.println("</div>");
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: You didn't show us the code for partition. But, it doesn't seem necessary anyway.  You could use a for loop to get the first 5 elements of your dataItems list.  Something like for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { out.println(dataItems.get(i));}

Comment: @rickz Thank you. I replaced the for (Object item : partition) with your for loop. It kinda works but the 6th item disappeared. It should be in next row. Do you still need the partition code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is demonstration code. It will work in a Servlet or a JSP.

```
    List<String> dataItems = List.of("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p");
    out.println("<table>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataItems.size(); i++) {
        if(i >= 5 && i % 5 == 0){
            out.println("</tr><tr>");
        }
        out.println("<td> " + dataItems.get(i) + " </td>");
    }
    out.println("</tr>");
    out.println("</table>");
```